Calculating ratio of area of two triangles...
In $\Delta ABC$, $D$ is the mid point of $BC$. $E$ is a point on $AC$ and $F$ is a point on $AB$. Given, $AE : EC = 2 : 1$ and $AF : FB = 3: 1$. Line segment $AD$ and $FE$ intersect at point $O$. What is the ratio of the area of $\Delta DOF$ to the area of $\Delta DOE$.
I have tried to solve this question using area base theorem. I have assumed total area of triangle $ABC$ as $24$ unit. So we will have area of triangle $ABD$ and $ADC$ as $12$ unit each. Again applying this taking $AF:FB$ base in triangle $ABD$, I got area of $AFD$ and $BFD$ as $9$ and $3$ unit respectively. Similarly in $ADC$ as $AF:FC$ base I got area of $ADE$ and $DEC$ as $8$ and $4$ unit respectively.
I'm stuck here, can't find asked area in question, I tried to apply MPG but it didn't work. Help me how to proceed next or maybe some other method?
The option were given
(A) $2:1$
(B) $7:5$
(C) $7:3$
(D) $9:8$
And please don't flag it down, I don't know how to use this platform properly but count it as some effort...
Edit: Thanks for solving my doubt.
I have solved this question using Mass point geometry too.So if someone see this in future I'm attaching this image .


Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What is the context of the question?  Are you a high school student?  College student?  If so, what is the name of your course?  When you say area base theorem, what is that?  I'm not aware that "Area base theorem" that is a universally used or accepted title.  Do you mean $A = \frac{b \cdot h}{ 2}$?  Also, what is "MPG"?
Although, I personally disagree, many on this site are post-bachelors in Math and downvote simpler exercises.  Please don't take it personally.

@nickalh I'm a graduated student. It's a question from a competitive examination .It must be done in 2 minutes maximum to clear the exam,such 30 questions come in exam which must be done in 40 minutes.Yes from area base I meant that if height is same then area will only be proportional to the base.

MPG is mass point geometry sir @nickalh

Here is a picture:

Using the notation $[XYZ]$ for the area of a triangle $\Delta XYZ$ we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{[DOF]}{[ABC]}
&=
\frac{[DOF]}{[DAF]}\cdot
\frac{[DAF]}{[DAB]}\cdot
\frac{[DAB]}{[ABC]}
=\frac {OD}{OA}\cdot \frac 34\cdot\frac 12\ ,
\\[3mm]
\frac{[DOF]}{[ABC]}
&=
\frac{[DOE]}{[DAE]}\cdot
\frac{[DAE]}{[DAC]}\cdot
\frac{[DAC]}{[ABC]}
=\frac {OD}{OA}\cdot \frac 23\cdot\frac 12\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so the wanted proportion is
$$\frac{[DOF]}{[DOE]}=\frac{3:8}{1:3}=\frac 98\ .
$$

Note: This is a supplement. In order to compute explicitly the portion of the area of each of the marked triangles $\Delta DOF$, $\Delta DOE$ in terms of $\Delta ABC$ we need also the position of $O$ on $AD$.
For this apply the theorem of Menelaus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &=
\frac{PB}{PC}\cdot
\frac{EC}{EA}\cdot
\frac{FA}{FB}
\ ,
&
\text{so }\frac{PB}{PC}&=\frac 23\ ,\text{ i.e. }PB=2BC=4BD\ ,\ PC=3BC=6BD\ ,
\\[3mm]
1 &=
\frac{OD}{OA}\cdot
\frac{FA}{FB}\cdot
\frac{PB}{PD}
\ ,
&
\text{so }\frac{OD}{OA}&=\frac 5{12}\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the last relation we ignore the sign, the orientation.
